# c# how to make a ComboBox not to drop down when I click on it?

Tags: c#, button, combobox

I have a `ComboBox` which I don't want to drop down when clicked. I need it to drop down when I click my `Button`. Any solutions?

Comment: You really need to define what platform (e.g. Winforms or WPF).

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: @CodyGray, While it is marked as duplicate, the linked answer is really not the best one (imho). And I can't provide my answer anymore, where you simply set `DropDownStyle` to `ComboBoxStyle.Simple` and than back to `ComboBoxStyle.DropDown` in combobox `DropDown` event, which effectively disallow to display drop-down list with any way (mouse, `F4`, `PgDown`, etc), without need to create own custom control.

Comment: @Sinatr So post your answer to the other question. That's the whole point of marking questions as duplicates: to consolidate all of the answers in one place.

Answer (score 0):

use the DroppedDown property to open up your combobox:

```
private void buttonOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.DroppedDown = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but first I need to make sure my ComboBox will not drop down then I click on it.